# Finding a specific node in xml hierarchy JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xslt, nodes, sax

I am using SAX to transform an XML document and remove nodes using an xsl:stylesheet (thanks to teppic). I'm not familiar with XML to understand how to edit the document.

xsl:

```
<!-- Copy -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Strip IMFile elements -->
<xsl:template match="IMFile"/>
```

This is getting all nodes of IMFile and deleting them perfectly. I now need to search nodes of type: Callout and see if any of their child of VectorNode's value is equal to TypeWinText and if so delete the entire Callout node. If not - do nothing.

```
Project_Data Version="8.00"> 
<CSMLData> 
<GoProject id="1" version="3.0" > <Project id="2" editRate="30/1" version="3.0" > 
<Timeline id="6" > 
<GenericMixer id="10" name="Unified Mixer"> 
<Tracks> 
<GenericTrack id="11" > 
<Medias> 
<Callout id="91" start="55" duration="20" scalar="1/1" mediaStart="25/1" mediaDuration="20/1" > 
<Attributes> 
<Attribute id="130" name="vectorNode"> 
<VectorNode id="131" kind="TypeWinSVG" > </VectorNode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding another empty template to remove *Callout* based on specific condition:

```
<xsl:template match="Callout[descendant::VectorNode/@kind='TypeWinText']"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate it! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In what position is the Callout node , could you be more specific?

To search if a node has the attribute x you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Keyframes">
 <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="Keyframe/@value='x'">
              //do what you want for example
           <xsl:value-of select="Keyframe/@value>
              // this will print "x"
         </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

you can apply the template by

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Keyframes"/>
```

Comment: GoProject/Project/Timeline/GenericMixer/Tracks/GenericTrack/Medias/Callout/Attributes/Attribute/VectorNode <- get Attribute "value" = x

Need to search each callout for that x value and if true remove the entire callout node. I will give your example a shot real quick!